# Picklist Field is not getting updated on Custom Object and Contact

Tags: apex, trigger, community

Hello guy's I'm trying to update the picklist field from this trigger but it is not getting updated when I printed the value it is showing NULL. Below is my trigger Handler class and Trigger. Rest Everything is working as expected.

```java
public with sharing class CreditReportTriggerHandler {

    public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<creditchecker__Credit_Report__c> listCreditReports){
        System.Debug('inside onBeforeUpdate ::');
        updateCreditDecision(listCreditReports);
    }

    public static void onAfterUpdate(List<creditchecker__Credit_Report__c> listCreditReports){
        System.Debug('inside onAfterUpdate ::');
        updateContactAndAccount(listCreditReports);
    }

    private static void updateCreditDecision(List<creditchecker__Credit_Report__c> listCreditReports){      

        if(listCreditReports != null && listCreditReports.size() > 0){
        for(creditchecker__Credit_Report__c oCredit : listCreditReports){
            System.debug('oCredit :: ' + oCredit);
            System.debug('oCredit.Fraud_Alert_Count__c :: ' + oCredit.Fraud_Alert_Count__c);
            System.debug('oCredit.creditchecker__Average_Score__c :: ' + oCredit.creditchecker__Average_Score__c);
            System.debug('oCredit.Decision__c :: ' + oCredit.Decision__c);
            creditchecker__Credit_Report__c oCreditReport = new creditchecker__Credit_Report__c();
            oCreditReport.Id = oCredit.Id;

            if((String.isBlank(oCredit.Decision__c) && oCredit.Fraud_Alert_Count__c == 0 && oCredit.creditchecker__Average_Score__c > Decimal.valueOf(System.Label.CreditDecision)) ||(oCredit.Decision__c != null && oCredit.Decision__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Approve')))
            {oCreditReport.Decision__c = 'Approve';}

            else if((String.isBlank(oCredit.Decision__c) && oCredit.creditchecker__Average_Score__c > 0 && oCredit.creditchecker__Average_Score__c < 600) || (oCredit.Decision__c != null && oCredit.Decision__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Deny')))
            {oCreditReport.Decision__c = 'Deny';}

            if(oCredit.creditchecker__Status_Description__c != null){ 
                if((oCredit.creditchecker__Status_Description__c.Contains('Frozen') || oCredit.creditchecker__Status_Description__c.Contains('Freeze')) && (oCredit.Decision__c != null && (!oCredit.Decision__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Approve') && !oCredit.Decision__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Deny'))))
                    oCreditReport.Decision__c = 'Frozen';
            }
            System.debug('oCreditReport :: ' + oCreditReport);

        }  }        

    }

    private static void updateContactAndAccount(List<creditchecker__Credit_Report__c> listCreditReports){
        Set<Id> setContactId = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id,creditchecker__Credit_Report__c> mapContactCreditReport = new Map<Id,creditchecker__Credit_Report__c>();
        Map<Id,Contact> mapAccountContact = new Map<Id,Contact>();
        System.debug('listCreditReports :: ' + listCreditReports);
        for(creditchecker__Credit_Report__c oCredit : listCreditReports){
            System.debug('inside updateContactAndAccount -- oCredit :: ' + oCredit);
            System.debug('inside updateContactAndAccount -- oCredit.creditchecker__Status__c :: ' + oCredit.creditchecker__Status__c);
            System.debug('inside updateContactAndAccount -- oCredit.Decision__c :: ' + oCredit.Decision__c);
            if(oCredit.creditchecker__Parent_Record_Id__c != null && oCredit.creditchecker__Parent_Record_Id__c.startsWith('003') && oCredit.creditchecker__Status__c == 'Completed'){
                setContactId.add(oCredit.creditchecker__Parent_Record_Id__c);
                mapContactCreditReport.put(oCredit.creditchecker__Parent_Record_Id__c, oCredit);  
            } 
        }

        List<Contact> lstContacts = new List<Contact>();

        if((mapContactCreditReport != null) && !mapContactCreditReport.isEmpty()){
            for(Id contactId : mapContactCreditReport.keySet()){
                creditchecker__Credit_Report__c oCreditReport = mapContactCreditReport.get(contactId);
                Contact oContact = new Contact();
                oContact.Id = contactId;  
                oContact.Decision__c = oCreditReport.Decision__c;
                oContact.Drivers_License__c = oCreditReport.Drivers_License__c;
                oContact.Relative_Name__c = oCreditReport.Relative_Name__c;
                oContact.Employer__c = oCreditReport.Employer__c;
                oContact.Social_Security_Number__c = '000000000';
                oContact.Birthdate = oCreditReport.creditchecker__Applicants_Date_Of_Birth__c;
                oContact.Fraud_Alert_Count__c = oCreditReport.Fraud_Alert_Count__c;
                lstContacts.add(oContact);             
            }
        }

        if(lstContacts != null && !lstContacts.isEmpty()) {
            try{
                Database.update(lstContacts,false) ;
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                System.debug('Contact Update Failed!' + lstContacts);
            }

        }
        for(Contact oContact: [Select Id, AccountId, FirstName,Is_Primary__c, LastName, Account.Type,Fraud_Alert_Count__c,Decision__c,creditchecker__Average_Score__c from Contact where Id in :setContactId ]) {
            if(String.isNotBlank(oContact.AccountId)){
                mapAccountContact.put(oContact.AccountId,oContact);
            }           
        }

        List<Account> listAccount = new List<Account>();
        if((mapAccountContact != null) && !mapAccountContact.isEmpty()) {            
            for(Id accountId : mapAccountContact.keySet()) {
                String accountType = mapAccountContact.get(accountId).Account.Type;
                Account oAccount = new Account();
                oAccount.Id = accountId;
                oAccount.creditchecker__Average_Score__c = mapAccountContact.get(accountId).creditchecker__Average_Score__c;
                oAccount.Fraud_Alert_Count__c = mapAccountContact.get(accountId).Fraud_Alert_Count__c;
                oAccount.Decision__c = mapAccountContact.get(accountId).Decision__c;
                if(String.isNotBlank(accountType) && accountType.equalsIgnoreCase('Prospect') && mapAccountContact.get(accountId).Is_Primary__c && (mapAccountContact.get(accountId).Decision__c =='Approve' || mapAccountContact.get(accountId).creditchecker__Average_Score__c > Decimal.valueOf(System.Label.CreditDecision))){
                    oAccount.Name = mapAccountContact.get(accountId).LastName + ',' + mapAccountContact.get(accountId).FirstName;
                }
                listAccount.add(oAccount);               
            }
        }

        if(listAccount != null && !listAccount.isEmpty()) {
            Database.update(listAccount,false) ;
        }
    }   
}
```

```java
trigger CreditReportTrigger on creditchecker__Credit_Report__c (after update, before update){
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.New != null && Trigger.New.size() > 0) {
           CreditReportTriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.New != null && Trigger.New.size() > 0) {
            CreditReportTriggerHandler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which picklist field?

Comment: @FlorianHeer Decision__c

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by just removing the object which i was creating in the update method.

Thanks everyone.